# How can I preserve certain files when compiling as a single .exe?

Tags: c#, .net-core, compilation

I am trying to compile my .NET Core application where all the assemblies are as one .exe and certain .csv and .txt files remain in the output.

I am using this command to compile as one .exe: `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true`

However, when I use this, my csv and txt files are not included in the output and my application does not work. I have tried setting their 'Copy to Output Directory' value as true, but this does not fix it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found:

You must add the `<ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>` tag to your project.csproj file items.

eg.

```
<None Update="additionaldata.csv">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
</None>
```